# While using CWM recovery on my nook touch I foolishly used a tool that wiped my entire partition, how do I fix it?

Tags: root-access, 2.1-eclair

My nook simple touch has been bricked by a tool designed to wipe all partitions that I found on a deep google search.

I can still boot up into CWM and attempted to use the backup to restore my nook to previous conditions.

Its obviously a vain attempt at this point to try anything else as I was capable to mount my internal nook partitions onto my ancient laptop.

The nook's partitions show up as unallocated on gparted.

Comment: Nothing there to revert to (factory reset doesn't restore anything, it just deletes user data). Only thing you can do is locate a matching ROM and flash that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by downloading a tool called noogie. You burn it onto the sdcard and on bootup you connect your working nook to a computer; preferably a Linux environment like Ubuntu and go to a program called Disks. 
[image]
You create a disk image file saved to your preferable location. After the image is complete you safely disconnect the nook and boot up onto noogie on the bricked nook and flash the image with the dd command. Using gparted or disk will pinpoint the location necessary for the text command. I would not recommend using the burn image option on the disk program as it will launch errors.

After the image is complete use the **dd** command to burn the image to the bricked nook's location.

```
sudo dd  if=/location/restore.img of=/dev/nook_location
```

The link below will give you the recovery tools needed.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/nst-recovery/downloads